# How to show database result in dropdown

Tags: android, sql-server, drop-down-menu

I am new to android. I have made Microsoft's SQL 2014 server connection with `JTDS.jar`. I want to create a drop down option menu in my android app that gets the entry from database.

Although, I can fetch the result from database using ResultSet and ResultSetMetaData but I am not sure, How would I show those results onto the dropdown. Also, how would make sure which option in drop down is selected.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377361/how-to-create-a-drop-down-list) answer shows how to create a drop down and show to populate the drop down list. What I need to ask is, do I need to store the database results into an array and then feed them to drop down or there is some other way around?

Comment: The dropdown (aka `Spinner`) is nothing but a view. What matters is the `Adapter` you will use. For instance, if you create an Adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter`, you will need to provide a `List` of objects as the adapter parameter. Anyway, for starters you shouldn't be connecting to the database directly from your app, try creating a web service to do that (Sinatra and Node.js are good ways to start). If you use the web service, its output can be the array of objects you need.