# Android: Want to make selection if more than 1 contact in contact book

Tags: android

How can i prompt a dialog box while pick up the contact from phone-book. The dialog box only should shown if particular person have more than 1 number in contact book otherwise no need to show a dialog, i can direct get that number. So my question is **How can i prompt a dialog box for a multiple number for a same person in contact-book**

Comment: can u elaborate it ? In which phase u are facing difficulty picking up number or in display. If you edit ur question with code then i may help. I want to know on which uri u are querying to get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming u are facing issue in UI for showing multiple contacts. You can use spinner to show drop down list and user can select one of its number from list. Spinner is well explained in following stackoverflow answer.

[How to add spinner in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377361/how-to-create-a-drop-down-list)