# ANDROID - how to save id POJO on spinner when button pressed using intent

Tags: android

can someone help me how to save `POJO` get id in spinner when button pressed??

I can save the pojo in spinner using `setOnItemClickListener` with this code

`Log.d("Id : ", world.get(position).getId());`

but how to get id of POJO using button? because when i want to try code above, the position getting error.

**EDIT**

i can show get id string with this code

```
    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("Id : ", world.get(position).getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

but how to implement above code in button `b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`?

i just stuck at this code

```
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        i.putExtra("nomor_matkul", String.valueOf(sp2.getSelectedItemPosition())); 
//here i want to save get id of pojo in spinner, but the `position` is getting error when i want to copy above code
        }
    }
```

Comment: show me your code

Comment: @DeepakKumar what code you need to see?

Comment: in where you stuck

Comment: @DeepakKumar can you help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377361/how-to-create-a-drop-down-list OR put above code (where you initialise Adapter and Spinner items )

Comment: @dondo, what is the error, put here the logcat message.

Comment: @AndreiT there is no error about the logcat, i just don't have an idea how to save POJO getid in spinner using button

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the selected item you need to use getSelectedItem.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                    "OnClickListener : " + 
                    "\n My Spinner : " + sp2.getSelectedItem(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

From here you can have access for the id and do whatever you want.
For a good tutorial I would recommend taking a look here:

[Android spinner (drop down list) example](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/)