# How to set string on Spinner Prompt programmatically?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

How to set the string values on spinner prompt?

The process how I am doing is:

I am able to retrieve the json data(it has only one single value), so I am getting the single text with the help of String.

Later, I am trying to set the string value in Spinner prompt

SP_gender is called as Spinner here. In String gender1, I have texts called as "male"

```
 String gender1 = i.getStringExtra("bundle_CusGender");
 SP_gender.setPrompt(gender1);
 System.out.println("Check bundle_CusGender = : " + gender1);
```

When I try to print this, I am getting a value as male

```
System.out: Check bundle_CusGender = : male
```

How should I set the single text in spinner Android?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the `setPrompt()` methods documentation states:

> Sets the prompt to display when the dialog is shown.

Which is pretty vague but internally it calls the `setPromptText()` method which sets the description on the popup and has the following documentation.

> Set hint text to be displayed to the user. This should provide
>   a description of the choice being made.

So if I am understanding your question correctly you want to set the spinners selected item. You should be using either `setSelection(int)` or `setSelection(int, boolean)`

For those to work you would need to give your spinner an adapter if you haven't already. If you don't know how you should check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17650125/2027232) which explains in more detail.