# Can't find Choose Device combobox in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Not able to find `Choose Device combobox`.

[image]

[image]

`adb devices` working fine while.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show a combobox in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024656/how-can-i-show-a-combobox-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I lost half a day on this issue and ended up fixing it by doing the following:
`Menu File → Invalidate Caches` and then do a restart.